# How to jump through a physic body (like a platform) and land on it (SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am trying to create a game in Objective-C like Mario / Sonic.

For now it works well but i still can't figure it out how I can make my hero from jumping though a physic body when he stands below it but can stand on top.

I was trying to create the physics body when the heros position is higher then the platform and to disable it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is actually not too difficult but the implementation into a full fledged game will be much more difficult for you. This is not something for a novice programmer to start out with.

First the same code project (tap/click on screen to jump up):

```
#import "GameScene.h"

typedef NS_OPTIONS(uint32_t, Level1PhysicsCategory) {
    CategoryPlayer  = 1 << 0,
    CategoryFloor0  = 1 << 1,
    CategoryFloor1  = 1 << 2,
};

@implementation GameScene {
    int playerFloorLevel;
    SKSpriteNode *node0;
    SKSpriteNode *node1;
    SKSpriteNode *node2;
}

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor whiteColor];

    node0 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor grayColor] size:CGSizeMake(400, 10)];
    node0.position = CGPointMake(300, 200);
    node0.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:node0.size];
    node0.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    node0.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CategoryFloor0;
    node0.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CategoryPlayer;
    [self addChild:node0];

    node1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor grayColor] size:CGSizeMake(400, 10)];
    node1.position = CGPointMake(300, 300);
    node1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:node1.size];
    node1.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    node1.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CategoryFloor1;
    node1.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CategoryPlayer;
    [self addChild:node1];

    node2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
    node2.position = CGPointMake(300, 250);
    node2.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:node2.size];
    node2.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CategoryPlayer;
    node2.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CategoryFloor0;
    [self addChild:node2];

    playerFloorLevel = 0;
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    if(((node2.position.y-25) > (node1.position.y+10)) && (playerFloorLevel == 0)) {
        node2.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CategoryFloor0 | CategoryFloor1;
        playerFloorLevel = 1;
    }
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
         CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
        //SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:touchLocation];

        // change 75 value to 50 to see player jump half way up through floor 1
        [node2.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 75)];
    }
}
```

The gist of the code is the player node (node2) has to keep checking its y position (update method) in relation to the other floors. In the example, the player jumps up through floor1. Once the player is higher than floor1, the player node's physics body modifies its collision bit mask to include floor1.

Sounds easy enough. However, in a real game you will have a large number of floors and all floors might not be evenly spaced y distances. You have to keep all that in mind when coding.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly!!! I don't set the collisionBitMask correctly, that was my mistake. Thanks